# What is the simplest way to make your program wait for a signal in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, asynchronous, wait, signals-slots

So I know in Qt, you can just put everything you want after a signal to happen into a slot, but when editting code later on; that can require a lot of restructuring, and may complicate things.

Is there a more simple way to hold your program until a signal is emitted in Qt, like say for example:

```
downloadImage();
Qt::waitForSignal(downloadImageFinished());
editImage();
```

Also; why doesn't something like this work:

```
// bool isFinished();
downloadImage(); // When done, isFinished() returns true;
while (!isFinished()) {}
editImage();
```

? Thanks.

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. The world around us isn't simple and doesn't evolve linearly. Things happen asynchronously. You need to structure the code to reflect this.

Pseudo-synchronous code that you present in the question is an implicit state machine. You'll gain more clarity and flexibility by making the stateful behavior explicit. *that can require a lot of restructuring, and may complicate things* Only if you do it wrong. Please edit your question to have a more complete example of what you're trying to do. That way one could address your unfounded presumptions of complexity.

Comment: @KubaOber Sometimes it has to be done - for example, to wait for all activities to finish and all locks to unlock before shutting down the program. I've run into this first when user pressed the 'X' window button during heavy video processing without stopping it - many threads were up and a lot of resources were allocated, leading to occasional crashes and warnings at shutdown when mutexes weren't unlocked properly.

Comment: When a user wants to close the window you have full control over whether that window gets closed, and over what feedback your code will offer to the user. Leontyev, You seem to have a very specific question, You could post a new self-contained question that creates some threads or whatnot, acquires locks, and demonstrates your problem. It will fit in <200 lines. Only then can a solution be presented that sidesteps the problems you expect. Otherwise, it's all too abstract to talk about.

Comment: @KubaOber Just because the world is asynchronous, does not necessarily mean that I should make a program asynchronous. With my example; I would of course need to download an image before I go ahead and attempt to edit it. In any case; I already have a good answer that I accepted. Thank you for your criticism though; in my next project, maybe I'll come and touch base with you in programming strategies for more asynchronous programming styles. Cheers.

Comment: @Akiva The problem is: your program **is** asynchronous. By pretending it isn't, you've set up yourself for a surprises (read: hard to reproduce bugs). Specifically, the `loop.exec()` can reenter any of your code. That's not insignificant even if we ignore the potential for infinite recursion.

Comment: @KubaOber Interesting point. shouldn't I just disconnect then?

Comment: No. The signal/slot mechanism doesn't affect the crux of the issue: writing pseudo-synchronous code.

Comment: Trust me, nested event loops will make maintaining your code much more difficult than writing proper asynchronous code.

Comment: I upvoted the answer because the question led to a very good answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically, you should do this:

```
    QEventLoop loop;
    connect(this, &SomeObject::someSignal, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
    // here you can send your own message to signal the start of wait, 
    // start a thread, for example.
    loop.exec(); //exec will delay execution until the signal has arrived
```

Wait inside a cycle will put your execution thread into a doom of spinlock - this shouldn't happen in any program. Avoid spinlocks at all cost - you don't want to deal with the consequences. Even if everything works right, remember that you will take whole processor core just for yourself, significantly delaying overall PC performance while in this state.

Comment: Also, make sure to confirm that signal isn't signaled BEFORE running QEventLoop::exec(). In case when asynchronous operation is sometimes(rarely though) finished fast enough for this to happen, it can create some hell of a bugs to find.

Comment: Best answer of them all.

Answer (score 0):

As the working of `downloadImage` is in another thread you can use a `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection` ([Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum)). This waits for a slot to complete prior to continuing with execution:

```
connect (this, &ThisType::triggerImageDownload,
         otherObject, &OtherType::downloadImage,
         Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection);
```

then

```
emit triggerImageDownload(); // This now blocks until downloadImage completes
editImage();
```